# Is there a php cdn?

Tags: php, cdn

I would like to rewrite my website from google sites to html. I have some knolage of php but, i would like to use netfly whitch is a free host and dose not support php. So, is there a line of HTML to include PHP?

Comment: Thats not how PHP works. PHP is parsed on the server, then the resulting HTML/... is sent to the client and the browser then parses the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere.

A CDN is a service that provides geographically localised, static files that browsers can download quickly.

PHP, in the context of the WWW, is a server-side programming language. It is never delivered to browsers. It can’t be included by a line of HTML.

Consequently, the idea of a CDN for PHP doesn’t make any sense.